# Get youtube comment Username

Tags: vb.net, youtube

I need help trying to get a YouTube comment Username to transferred from the web browser to a listbox. I am trying to do this without the YouTube API. I have been searching for a while now and got nothing.

Comment: You could pull the HTML source code and parse out the comments along with usernames. The '<ul id=:"all-comments">' houses the individual comments, and the subsequent comment classes can provide the user names as a link '<a href="/user/randomName'

Comment: Why would you do it without the youtube API?  It's probably a million times easier...

Comment: Because then he would get caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, for example you have this video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sn67KEiDPLY). Now you want to get the comment authors. You should create a webbrowser and after webbrowser navigates to the video, on documentcomplete you can detect all authors:

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
            Dim ElementClass As String = "author"

            If element.OuterHtml.Contains(ElementClass) Then
                Dim aclass = "yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name"
                If element.FirstChild.OuterHtml.Contains("yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name") Then
                    MsgBox(element.FirstChild.InnerText)
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

MSgBox will show you each author. But you can write them to the ListBox. You can add the TextBox to manage urls of the videos. So the final code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
            Dim ElementClass As String = "author"

            If element.OuterHtml.Contains(ElementClass) Then
                Dim aclass = "yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name"
                If element.FirstChild.OuterHtml.Contains("yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name") Then
                    ListBox1.Refresh()
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(element.FirstChild.InnerText)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

And so you can add comments like this:

```
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        Dim ElementClass As String = "comment-text"

        If element.OuterHtml.Contains(ElementClass) Then
            Dim divclass = "comment-text"
            If element.Parent.InnerHtml.Contains(divclass) Then

                ListBox1.Refresh()
                ListBox1.Items.Add(element.InnerText)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

It's works with Webbrowser control, but @ObieMD5 is right - it will be easier with Youtube API.

Comment: I used your final code but when I debug it, I get an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on this line `If element.FirstChild.OuterHtml.Contains("yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name") Then`